# How to copy csv file from s3 to mysql rds

Tags: python-3.x

I had written a code in python connecting to rds(Mysql),the connection was sucessfull but when iam trying to copy a csv file from s3 its not working

```
# Begin your transaction
cur.execute("begin;")
cur.execute("copy public.a from 's3://XXXXXXX/a.csv' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXx ;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXX' csv;")
# Commit your transaction
cur.execute("commit;")
print("Copy executed fine!")
```

I am not getting any error. I can connect to rds and create a table in that but I can't load that data from s3

```
import mysql.connector 

REGION = 'us-east-1' 
rds_host = "XXXX" 
name = "xxxx" 
password = "XXXX" 
db_name = "XXX" 

def mysql_connector(): 
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='XXXX', password='XXXX', host='XXXX', port= 3306, database='XXXX', use_unicode=True)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute( "create table a(_c0 varchar(20),_c1 varchar(20),_c2 varchar(30),_c3 varchar(30),_c4 varchar(30),_c5 varchar(30),value varchar(30),status varchar(20));")
```

After this I begin transaction from s3 to rds but I can't commit my transaction.

Comment: What is the error that you get ?

Comment: hey pratham,Iam not getting any error. I can able to connect  to rds and create a table in that but can't able to load that daata from s3

Comment: @Pratham you can see my code above after this i begin transaction from s3 to rds but cant able to commit my transaction

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, you can [edit] your question and format it properly